# Trying to add a new bucket in firebase storage. Cannot find GCP Mumbai(asia-south1). Any clue?

Tags: firebase-storage

[This link](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/) shows GCP Mumbai is launched. However when I go to my firebase billing account and try to add a new bucket from firebase console, cannot find Mumbai(asia-south1) region listed.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create bucket in Mumbai GCP in Google cloud console.
2. Go to firebase console -> storage -> add bucket
3. Select "Import existing Google Cloud Storage buckets"
4. Buckets will be listed
5. Select bucket created in Mumbai GCP in Google cloud console
6. Select continue to import

Answer (score 0):

I believe your current Firebase project is in a region that did have the Firebase Storage enabled. In this case, you will have to create a new Firebase project and select the location of your Firebase project to Mumbai, so you can create your buckets within this location, regions change is not supported in Firebase yet.