# How To Integrate/Access Existing GCP Storage Bucket To Firebase Swift App Programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I create buckets on GCP Storage using the Node.js library. Later, I want to access these GCP Storage buckets from my Firebase iOS app. However, I can't. I receive the following error when trying to access my existing GCP buckets from my iOS app:

`Your bucket has not been set up properly for Firebase Storage. Please visit https://console.firebase.google.com/project/MY_PROJECT/storage/files to automatically repair this issue and then retry. If the issue lasts longer than five minutes, you may have insufficient permissions to repair the project. You can check your permissions by visiting https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=MY_PROJECT."`

It seems like I need to go to the Firebase Storage console and ***manually*** import existing Google Cloud Storage buckets to my Firebase project (as suggested [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/multiplying-power-firebase-storage.html)).

How can I import existing GCP Storage buckets to my iOS Firebase project programmatically? Or, is there a way to access existing GCP buckets and perform operations on them from my iOS app using Firebase Storage library?

Note: I'm on the Blaze plan. `firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com` is added to my existing GCP buckets as Storage admin, just like it is for my default Firebase Storage bucket.

Here's a screenshot from Firebase console that explains the situation.
[image: Firebase Screenshot]

Comment: You only have problems when trying to access your GCS buckets, right? No additional issues when trying to access your Firebase Storage buckets?  Also, do you use that service account within your code?

Comment: I face no issues accessing Firebase Storage buckets. As you mentioned, I face issues accessing GCS buckets. Yesterday I created a GCS bucket using Cloud functions, then manually imported that GCS bucket using the Firebase console following the instructions on the link above. I was able to access my GCS bucket. I do not use that service account within my code. I didn't have use the service account to access my newly created and Firebase accessible GCS bucket.

Comment: So you now can access to your GCS bucket from your app?

Comment: I want to access my GCS buckets without having to manually importing them from the Firebase Storage website. I want to import my GCS buckets to Firebase from code. I want to know whether that is possible.

Comment: If I'm unclear I can send a screenshot, let me know!

Comment: Yeah, It'd be great if you could add the screenshot to the question

Comment: Please see the attached screenshot above.

Comment: @ddeger Did you find a solution for this? Have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a doc which talks about [The Firebase integration with Google Cloud Platform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration). It says:

> Cloud Storage for Firebase is tightly integrated with Google Cloud Platform. The Firebase SDKs for Cloud Storage store files directly in Google Cloud Storage buckets.

Meaning that there shouldn't be problems when trying to call your GCS buckets from your app. There are a number of ways to access data stored in your Cloud Storage bucket, depending on what you want to do.

For the integration itself, I found this [GCS buckets and Firebase Quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start). Yes, it's mentioned that you need to specify your bucket's location.

It's mentioned that

> Read and write access to Storage is restricted so only authenticated users can read or write data

Meaning that you have to implement an authentication process within your app. Check also the [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) so we can also get rid of the `insufficient permissions` part.

Hope this is helpful.

EDIT: Maybe I forgot to mention about the [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start). After you set them, your app (and your users) will have access to your GCS buckets.
I also found a very similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158874/trying-to-add-a-new-bucket-in-firebase-storage-cannot-find-gcp-mumbaiasia-sout).

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your answer. I'm unclear about one thing. firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com is already added to the GCS bucket as a Storage Admin. Whenever I make requests to any bucket that firebase-storage account is used. Because the requests are fired from iOS app. Therefore, why would I need to authenticate this user? It is a user that has permissions to access a certain GCS bucket. If I need to, it seems like I need to add this account to my Firebase Auth database. But then how would I make requests to GCS buckets using credentials of this firebase-storage account user?

Answer (score 0):

Having encountered the same issue, I'm afraid there is no available programmatic solution right now.

Even if a bucket is created from the Admin SDK in a cloud function, it is not automatically attached to the Firebase project, which is required to apply some security rules and use it on the client side.

The attachment process itself looks like a black box. There is no IAM apparent change after the bucket selection and process validation in the Firebase console.

So, at this date, **I would not recommend using custom buckets** in Firebase projects for the following reasons:

- It appears not possible to programmatically attach a custom bucket to a Firebase Project, the only working method being a manual addition via the web console
- Regarding the very promising `admin.securityRules()` functions namespace, this is quite new (end of 2019) and the documentation lacks some thorough examples.

Comment: Please [edit] to steer away from the "Me too." impression and the "Could you help?" impression. I think both impressions are wrong and you really attempt to helpfully answer. But I recommend to make thatmore obvious. (you could e.g. delete the "same issue" part and move the "Dear team..." part into comment)

Comment: Actually there is a change in IAM; the `firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com` member gets added with `Storage Admin` role. But it is not enough, there is something else going on.